# Swift: MapKit - Recognize Pin Tap

Tags: ios, swift

I must be missing something obvious here.....

Works: 
Add a bunch of MKPointAnnotations from Core Data...shows on Map

Does Not Work: 
Try to have a print statement appear when a pin is tapped.

I have the MKMapView Delegate set and did not implement AnnotationView since I wish to segue immediately after a pin is tapped. Would rather not show a context dialog.

What am I missing to recognize a pin is tapped?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import Foundation
import CoreData

class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {    
    @IBOutlet weak var mapOutlet: MKMapView!

    var latitude = 100.0 as Double
    var longitude = 120.0 as Double

    var pins = [NSManagedObject]()

    func pullPins()    {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Pin")

        do {
            let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            pins = results as! [NSManagedObject]

            for pin in pins {
                let pinLat = pin.valueForKey("latitude") as! Double
                let pinLon = pin.valueForKey("longitude") as! Double

                let pinCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: pinLat, longitude: pinLon)

                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = pinCoordinate

                self.mapOutlet.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }


    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
        print("Pin Tapped")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pullPins()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not receiving a map view delegate message, it is because you have not made yourself the map view's delegate. For example:

```
self.mapOutlet.delegate = self
```